# Change div background-image on a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I have a button-based menu that refers to content of the page. It is animated by some jquery I found on the net.
My goal is to change the `background-image` to certain image while clicking certain button (ex. when I click "historia" button the background image changes to historia.png) but at the same time keep the scrolling down to referring section working.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
 z-index: 2;
}

body {
 background-size: cover;
}

/* tło */
.background {
 position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
 background-image: url(mainback.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 filter: blur(2px;);
 -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}

.undefinedheader {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: auto;
 top: 8vh;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.63);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
}
.container {
 height: 420px;
 background-color: blue;
  top: 30vh;
  width:100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #a62a71, #963680, #83408c, #6d4993, #565096, #4560a6, #2e70b2, #007fba, #009ed0, #00bee0, #1cddeb, #5ffbf1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.63);
  transform: translateY(50%);
 display: block;
}

.internal-width {
 padding: 0;
  width: 90vmin;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.box
{
 width: 220px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #22584F;
 margin:1%;
 flex-basis:calc(94% / 3);
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 20px;
 position: relative;
 font-family: fantasy;
 font-size: 4vw;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.box:hover
{
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 cursor: pointer;
 transform: scale(1.1);
}


/* zawartość indeksu */


section {
 height: 100vh;
 padding: 0;
}

section:nth-child(2){
 display: flex;
}
section:before{
 content: attr(data-text);

}

.starttext {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 0;
}
.internal-box1{

 position: relative;
 width: 90vw;
 top: 45%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.contentbox {
 width: 250px;
 height: 80px;
 background-color: #22584F;
 margin:1%;
 flex-basis:calc(110% / 5);
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 20px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 2.4vw;
 line-height: 80px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

.contenttitle{
 position: relative;
 background-color: grey;
 width: 70vw;
 height: 80px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 5vw;
 line-height: 80px;
}

.description {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 20px;
 width: 75vw;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 font-size: 40px;
 line-height: 35px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-family: monospace;
}

.contentbox:hover
{
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 cursor: pointer;
 transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* zmiana tła */

#history:hover .background {
 background-image: url(1back.png);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "stylei.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
    // target element id
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    // target element
    var $id = $(id);
    if ($id.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // prevent standard hash navigation (avoid blinking in IE)
    e.preventDefault();

    // top position relative to the document
    var pos = $(id).offset().top;

    // animated top scrolling
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: pos
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<div class="background" id="back"></div>

<body>

<section id="top">
<div class="starttext" id="start">1</div>
<div class="undefinedheader">
tu może być tytuł
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="internal-width">
 <a class="box" href="#1">Historia</a>
 <a class="box" href="#2"></a>
 <a class="box" href="#3"></a>
 <a class="box" href="#4"></a>
 <a class="box" href="#5"></a>
 <a class="box" href="#6"></a>
 </div>
</div>
</section>

<section  id="1">
<div class="starttext">pisanie</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="contenttitle">Historia gier planszowych</div>
    <div class="description">
    Gry planszowe jak się okazuje, są dużo starsze niż większości z nas się wydaje, bowiem już około 5000 lat temu ludzie zaczęli tworzyć pierwsze gry planszowe.
    </div>
    <div class="internal-box1">


      <a class="contentbox" href="antiq_pl.html">starożytność</a>
      <a class="contentbox" href="medieval_pl.html">średniowiecze</a>
      <a class="contentbox" href="present_pl.html">czasy nowożytne</a>
      <a class="contentbox" href="#top">do gory</a>

    </div>
</div>
</section>


<section id="2">
<div class="starttext">pisanie</div>
<div class="container">tekst
  <div class="internal-box1">
    <div class="contentlink"></div>
    <div class="contentbox"></div>
    <div class="contentbox"></div>
    <div class="contentbox"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>

<section id="3">
<div class="starttext">pisanie</div>
<div class="container">tekst</div>
</section>

<section id="4">
<div class="starttext">pisanie</div>
<div class="container">tekst</div>
</section>

<section id="5">
<div class="starttext">pisanie</div>
<div class="container">tekst</div>
</section>

<section id="6">
<div class="starttext">pisanie</div>
<div class="container">tekst</div>
</section>

</body>
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I want an effect that when I click a button the background will change. Sorry for not _being on point_.

Comment: No, that's what you want to achieve. What specific programming question do you have? We're not a code writing service. We expect you'll do lots of research first, then make an attempt and then, if you have a ***specific*** question, you'll post what you've done and your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try below CSS:

```
.internal-width a:nth-child(1):active {
   background-image:url(filenmae.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Target the button with the click event after that in the function target the element with the background-image and change it's url.

$(btn).click(function(){ elementWithBackgroundImage.css('background-image', 'url')});